# Moving exiting elements to top in DOM

Tags: d3.js

Is there a simple way of reordering (sending to top) the exiting DOM elements before removing?

The reason I want to do this is that there is no other z-index rendering order other than DOM order.
I want my exiting elements to be covered by entering and updating elements. If they are moved upwards in the DOM they will be covered by elements below. 
For entering elements this is of course not a problem since I simply append them to the bottom or insert them like `.insert("g",":first-child")` to get them on top.

Optionally I could move the updating and entering elements down. If that is easier.

But how do I move elements?

Comment: You could try [`sort`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-sort), but you won't have access to the different selections that way.

Comment: And therefore it is pointless.

Comment: Not entirely pointless, you just have to do the matching of data elements to document elements yourself.